# How to encode a list name for REST in sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, rest, url, sharepoint, encoding

I created a list in the `en` site called

> hello's~`!@#$%^&*(){}[]:;"'<>?/\|*-+.

What I am trying to do is figure out what exactly is the encoded version of the name if I am trying to target it by name in a REST url. I have this

> http://mysite/en/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('hello's~`!@#$%^&*(){}[]:;"'<>?/\|*-+.')

but this doesn't work of course. I tried url encoding it to

> http://mysite/en/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('hello%27s~%60!%40%23%24%25%5E%26*()%7B%7D%5B%5D%3A%3B%22%27%3C%3E%3F%2F%5C%7C*-%2B.')

but even then, doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: if it's part of a path, then you need to use `encodeURI(str)`

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

> hello's~`!@#$%^&(){}[]:;"'<>?/\|-+.

contains at least  the following *invalid* symbols `<,>,*,%,&,:,\\,?` (follow [`HttpRuntimeSection.RequestPathInvalidCharacters` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters(v=vs.110).aspx) for a more details)

So, if list title contains any of the specified invalid symbols then `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client` error will be returned in REST request.

Regarding `'` (single quote) symbol, it should be properly escaped by replacing it with  `''` (double quote) symbol.